# Finding largest Integer C++

Tags: c++, arrays

> Given an array A of N integers, return the largest integer K>0 such that both values K and -K(the opposite number) exist in Array A. If there is no such integer, the function should return 0.
>
> Example:
>
> 1. Given A = [4,-4,-4,2] the function should return 4
> 2. Given A = [ -2,0,0,-3], the function should return 0, as there is no such K>0
> 3. Given A = [-4], the function should return 0

Here are some of the code that I've implemented, but still trying to figure out the exact implementation for getting the largest value in the array.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

int solution(vector<int>& A) {
    sort(A.begin(), A.end());
    int first = 0, last = A.size() - 1;

    while (first < last) {
        if (A[first] = -A[last])
            return A[last];

        if (A[first] > -A[last])
            last -= 1;
        else
            first += 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (A[first] = -A[last])` is doing assignment. `==` is for checking equality.

Comment: Turn on warnings - the compiler really wants to help you solve things like this.

Comment: Seems if the vector/array is sorted, you just need to look at the last value in `A` and verify that it is non-negative right?  No need for loops.

Comment: Try taking the vector by const reference `const vector<int>&`, then the compiler will suddently tell you where your errors are.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: `[-5, -2, 1, 2, 3, 7]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (A[first] = -A[last])
```

is wrong, you probably want:

```
if (A[first] == -A[last])
```

(the first one is a assignment, the second one is a comparison)

Answer (score 1):

I would start by creating two sets, one of positive numbers, the other of the absolute values of the negative numbers.

Then I'd do a set intersection between the two. The largest value in the result is the value you're looking for (and if the result is empty, you return 0).

```cpp
int solve(std::vector<int> const &input) {
    std::set<int> pos;
    std::set<int> neg;
    std::set<int> abs;

    std::copy_if(input.begin(), input.end(), std::inserter(pos, pos.end()), [](int i) { return i > 0;} );
    std::copy_if(input.begin(), input.end(), std::inserter(neg, neg.end()), [](int i) { return i < 0; });
    std::transform(neg.begin(), neg.end(), std::inserter(abs, abs.end()), [](int i) { return -i; });

    std::set<int> merged;
    std::set_intersection(pos.begin(), pos.end(), abs.begin(), abs.end(), std::inserter(merged, merged.end()));
    if (merged.empty())
        return 0;
    return *std::prev(merged.end(), 1);
}
```

It would be nice of there was a `transform_if` that let you find items that met a certain criteria, and transform them in a single step.

Alternatively, the ranges library could simplify this (at least syntactically) quite a bit.

Just for what it's worth, a quick bit of test code:

```cpp
int main() { 
    std::vector<std::pair<std::vector<int>, int>> inputs {
        { { 4, -4, -4, 2}, 4 },
        { { -2,0, 0, -3}, 0 },
        { { -4}, 0 }
    };

    for (auto [input, result] : inputs) {
        int res;
        if ((res=solve(input)) != result) {
            std::cerr << "Error. Result: " <<  res << " != " << result << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, with `std::sort` and `std::adjacent_find`, you might do:

```
int solve(std::vector<int>& v)
{
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int lhs, int rhs){
        auto proj = [](int n){ return std::tuple(std::abs(n), 0 < n); };

        return proj(lhs) > proj(rhs);
    });
    auto it = std::adjacent_find(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int lhs, int rhs){ return lhs == -rhs; });
    return it != v.end() ? *it : 0;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc6e86ee33112733)